# How to fix this issue of table cells cutting off in custom calendar in PHP?

Tags: php

I have built a custom calendar in PHP. The calendar works fine except one issue. The problem is that for some months e.g. `August 2021, September 2021`, etc., the remaining empty table cells after date `31 or 30`, are cutting off - actually the `<td>s` are not generating at all.

How to modify the logic so that empty cells should be drawn with `<td>&nbsp;</td>` in such scenario - just like I did in the starting of month.

`// Blank cells before the month starts if($i < $start_day){$calendar .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>";}`

This is the issue:

[image]

[image]

But for current month "July" 2021, the table renders properly:

[image]

Here's my complete code:

```
<?php
function display_calendar($current_month, $current_year, $disable_prev_days = false, $go_to_date = false)
{
    $prev_year = $next_year = $current_year;
    $prev_month = $current_month - 1;
    $next_month = $current_month + 1;
    
    if($prev_month == 0)
    {
        $prev_month = 12;
        $prev_year = $current_year - 1;
    }

    if($next_month == 13)
    {
        $next_month = 1;
        $next_year = $current_year + 1;
    }
    
    $month = date("n");
    $year = date("Y");  
    
    $prev_year_link = "<a href='?month=" . $current_month . "&year=" . ($current_year - 1) . "'>&laquo; Prev Year</a>";
    $prev_month_link = "<a href='?month=" . $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year . "'>&laquo; Prev Month</a>";
    $next_month_link = "<a href='?month=" . $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year . "'>Next Month &raquo;</a>";
    $next_year_link = "<a href='?month=" . $current_month . "&year=" . ($current_year + 1) . "'>Next Year &raquo;</a>";

    $title = date("F", strtotime($current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-01"));

    $calendar = "<table class='tb_calendar'><tr>";
    $calendar .= "<tr><th>" . $prev_year_link . "</th>";
    $calendar .= "<th>" . $prev_month_link . "</th>";
    $calendar .= "<th colspan='3'><h3>" . $title . " " . $current_year . "</h3></th>"; 
    $calendar .= "<th>" . $next_month_link . "</th>";
    $calendar .= "<th>" . $next_year_link . "</th></tr><tr>";
    
    $weekdays = array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
    foreach($weekdays as $weekday)
    {
        $calendar .= "<th>" . $weekday . "</th>";
    }
    
    $calendar .= "</tr>";
    
    $today = date("d");
    $timestamp = strtotime($current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-01");
    $date_arr = getdate($timestamp);
    
    $start_day = $date_arr['wday'];
    
    $total_days = date("t", $timestamp);

    for($i = 0; $i < $total_days + $start_day; $i++)
    {
        if($i % 7 == 0)
        {
            $calendar .= "<tr>";
        }

        if($i < $start_day)
        {
            $calendar .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            $calendar .= "<td>";
            $day = $i - $start_day + 1;
            
            if($day < $today && $month == $current_month && $disable_prev_days == true)
            {
                $calendar .= "<span class='past_days'>" . $day . "</span>";
            }
            elseif($day == $today && $month == $current_month && $year == $current_year)
            {
                $calendar .= "<span id='today'>" . $day . "</span>";
            }
            else
            {
                $calendar .= "<span>" . $day . "</span>";
            }

            $calendar .= "</td>";
        }
        
        if($i % 7 == 6)
        {
            $calendar .= "</tr>";
        }
    }
    
    if(($i % 7) != 0 )
    {
        $calendar .= "</tr>";
    }

    $calendar .= "</table>";

    return $calendar;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>PHP</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .tb_calendar {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        max-width:1200px;
        width: 100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        font-size:14px;
        background:#FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .tb_calendar th {
        border:1px solid #dddddd;
        font-size:15px;
        padding:10px 5px;
        font-weight:normal;
        color:#000000;
    }

    .tb_calendar td {
        border:1px solid #dddddd;
        padding:5px;
        width: 14.29%;
    }

    .tb_calendar h3 {
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:normal;
        color:#000000;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    
    .tb_calendar a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000000;
    }

    .tb_calendar a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    
    .tb_calendar .past_days {
        color:#cccccc;
    }
    
    .tb_calendar #today {
        color:#ff0000;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <?php
    // Default month and year
    $current_month = (isset($_GET['month']) && is_numeric($_GET['month']) && $_GET['month'] > 0) ? (int) $_GET['month'] : date("n");
    $current_year = (isset($_GET['year']) && is_numeric($_GET['year']) && $_GET['year'] > 0) ? (int) $_GET['year'] : date("Y");

    echo display_calendar($current_month, $current_year);
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to track the "active" column that is being written to for each row:

```
if($i % 7 == 0)
{
    $calendar .= "<tr>";
    $column = 0; //reset column counter on each new row
}
$column++; //increment column
```

Then, if at the end of the calendar the column number is less than the number of days in the week, create an empty cell for each of the remaining columns:

```
if(($i % 7) != 0 )
{
   $diff = sizeof($weekdays)-$column; //calculate difference between the number of weekdays and the current column
        
    for($d=0; $d<$diff; $d++) { //output an empty cell for the number of differences
        $calendar .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    }
   $calendar .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Your solution fixed my problem.